# Python regex to match whole words (minus contractions and possessives)

Tags: python, regex, spell-checking

I am trying to using regex in Python to capture whole words from text. This is simple enough but I also want to remove contractions and possessives indicated by apostrophes.

Currently I have `(?iu)(?<!')(?!n')[\w]+`

Testing on the following text

> One tree or many trees? My tree's green. I didn't figure this out yet.

Gives these matches

> One tree or many trees My tree green I didn figure this out yet

In this example the negative lookbehind prevents the "s" and "t" after an apostrophe from being matched as whole words. But how do I write the negative lookahead `(?!n')` so that the matches include "did" instead of "didn"?

(My use case here is a simple Python spell checker, each word gets validated as being spelt correctly or not. I've ended up using the [autocorrect module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect/0.1.0) as pyenchant, aspell-python and others didn't work when installed via pip)

Comment: what output are you expecting? Are you using `re.match`, `re.sub`, `re.findall`?

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r"(?u)\w+(?:'\w+)*", s)`](https://regex101.com/r/449L1M/1).

Comment: @asongtoruin I'm using `re.finditer` to iterate through matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this regex:

```
(?<![\w'])\w+?(?=\b|n't)
```

This matches word characters until it encounters `n't`.

Result:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<![\w'])\w+?(?=\b|n't)", "One tree or many trees? My tree's green. I didn't figure this out yet.")
['One', 'tree', 'or', 'many', 'trees', 'My', 'tree', 'green', 'I', 'did', 'figure', 'this', 'out', 'yet']
```

---

Breakdown:

```
(?<!         # negative lookbehind: assert the text is not preceded by...
    [\w']    # ... a word character or apostrophe
)
\w+?         # match word characters, as few as necessary, until...
(?=
    \b       # ... a word boundary...
|            # ... or ...
    n't      # ... the text "n't"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's precisely what I'm after.